# ORMLITE order by a column from another table

Tags: android, join, ormlite

I would like to get information by a sql like this but in "ORMLITE"

```
SELECT * FROM tableA a INNER JOIN tableB b on a.fieldA = b.fieldB
     ORDER BY a.fieldZ, b,fieldX;
```

I try this in ORMLITE:

```
QueryBuilder<B, Integer> bQuery = bDao.queryBuilder();
bQuery.orderby("fieldX", true);

QueryBuilder<A, String> aQuery = aDao.queryBuilder();
aQuery.orderby("fieldZ", true);

list = (List<T>) aQuery.join(bQuery).query();
```

But the result is not correct because it is not order by `a.fieldZ`. How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31345639/1005102

Answer (score 3):

instead :

```
aQuery.orderby("fieldZ", true);
```

you should use :

```
aQuery.orderbyRaw("a.fieldZ, b.fieldX");
```

it's work for me