# ORMlite join and order by over three tables

Tags: sql, join, many-to-many, sql-order-by, ormlite

I have a many to many relationship and am trying to order by the one side. So in SQL this would be:

```
select * from 
patient join patientuserrelation on patient.id=patientuserrelation.p_id
join user on patientuserrelation.u_id=user.id
order by user.name
```

Which I have implemented in Ormlite as:

```
QueryBuilder<Visit, String> qbVisit = setupAccess(Visit.class)
                .queryBuilder();
QueryBuilder<UserVisitRelation, String> qbUserVisitRelation = setupAccess(
                        UserVisitRelation.class).queryBuilder();
QueryBuilder<User, String> qbUser = setupAccess(User.class)
                    .queryBuilder();
qbUser.orderBy(sortByThisColumn, true);
qbUserVisitRelation.join(qbUser);
qbVisit.join(qbUserVisitRelation);

return qbVisit.distinct().query();
```

However, this does not work. The results are not ordered at all. I could try to use rawSQL and rawRowMapper but that bloat up my code.
There is a similar question here: [ORMLITE order by a column from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708538/ormlite-order-by-a-column-from-another-table). Unfortunately with no answer. Is there a helpful expert around?

Comment: I have seen the order by to work when joining two tables, but it doesn't seem to work over three. :(

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to answer my own question for posterity: It seems like join and order across multiple tables is not supported in ormlite 4.48. If you think about it for a while you figure out why this is probably the case. Anyway, the solution is to write a raw sql statement, only select the necessary columns WITHOUT foreign collections and cast it to your object using RawRowMapper and GenericRawResults. Not what you like to do when using an ORM, but OK.